# binding laravel blade value to modal template in vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel page where I'm using Vue to populate a modal for corresponding rows in a table with links. Each row has a link which pops up the modal, and the idea is that the modal will have the info corresponding to the clicked row

What I can't figure out: In my example here, my header h2 element is showing the name and number properly. However, the textarea and hidden input are completely blank, even though the content is there in the html table when I test it. In other words, I have all the content I need but I want each modal to hold the content and contentID for an eventual axios call.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    @foreach($results as $k => $results)
    <tr class="" id="">
        <td>
            <a id="show-row-modal" @click="showModal = {{$k}}; getDetails('{{$results->contentID}}');">{{$results->number}}</a>
            <modal v-if="showModal==={{$k}}" @close="showModal = false">
            <h2 slot="header">{{$results->number}}-{{$results->name}}</h2>

            <div slot="body">
            <textarea style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;" v-model="resultsContent">{{utf8_encode($results->content)}}</textarea>
            <input type="hidden" value='{$results->contentID}' v-model="existingContentID" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach


    <script type="text/x-template" id="row-modal-template">
      <transition name="rowModal">
        <div class="modal-mask">
          <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-container">
            <div class="uk-grid">
              <div class="modal-header uk-form-row uk-width-1-1">
                <slot name="header">
                  default header
                </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body uk-form-row uk-width-1-1">
                <slot name="body">
                  default body
                </slot>
              </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </script>

     Vue.component('modal',{
    template: '#row-modal-template'
    })

    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: { 
            showModal: false,
            existingCopyID: [''],
            resultsContent: [''],
        },
```

Comment: The value on your hidden input does not appear to be valid blade syntax.  Try changing `value='{$results->contentID}'` to `value="{{$results->contentID}}"` and see if this fixes the hidden field.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `@foreach($results as $k => $results)` be `@foreach($results as $k => $result)` with `$result` singular?  You appear to be overwriting the variable `$results`.

Comment: @matticustard Thanks for that, fortunately the result/results issue was a typo here, and is correct in my code. I did however fix the first issue with brackets but still the same issue. Since I'm creating a modal for each row and they're pre-rendered it seems that this is my main issue on the VUe side

Comment: It might also be worth noting that HTML doesn't like multiple elements with the same id as you are defining at `<a id="show-row-modal" `.